# Clearing class instance variables in between Rspec examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2

I'm writing specs for a gem of mine that extends ActiveRecord. One of the things it has to do is set a class instance variable like so:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  @foo = "asd"
end
```

Right now when I set @foo in one `it "should" {}` it persists to the next one. I understand this is normal Ruby behavior but I thought RSpec had some magic that cleaned everything out in between specs. I'd like to know how I can re-use a single AR model for all my tests (since creating a bunch of tables would be a pain) while being sure that @foo is being cleared between each test. Do I need to do this manually?

Comment: "I thought RSpec had some magic that cleaned everything out in between specs" - can anyone comment on whether this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up generating a method in my helper class that generated new classes with Class.new, so I could be sure that nothing was being left over in between tests.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply make good use of the `after :each` block.

```
after(:each) do 
  @foo = nil
end
```

Comment: or even an around statement that remembers the value before the test and sets it back afterwards.

Comment: the author's instance variable is in the class under test, NOT in the test itself.